# error while trying to build multi-node DSE cluster

Tags: datastax-enterprise

Im trying to build a three node DSE cluster. I have installed DSE 4.5.6 in node1(ip1) node2(ip2) node3(ip3). I have configured cassandra.yaml as below.
        cluster_name= DSE(same in all nodes)
        seed= ip1(same in all nodes)
        listen_port=respective ip's for each node.
and strated the dse services and checked nodetool status. It shows only node1 in the ring. Im i missing any configurations.?

Comment: can your nodes access each other via the network?

Comment: what did you use for the rpc_address in cassandra.yaml on each node? in your question, you say listen_**port** = respective ip. It should be listen_address instead. or maybe you made a typo

Comment: when i tried telnet, i was getting no route to host exception. #phact

Comment: yes,it was a typo mistake :) #LHWizard

Comment: no route to host sounds like a network problem. so you will have to open the ports listed in the [datastax documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.6/datastax_enterprise/install/installAMIsecurity.html)